# How do I transplant this California walnut sapling?

Tags: plant-care, transplanting, repotting

This sapling seems to be a California walnut. Unfortunately it is growing in this narrow patch and it'll end up breaking the fence for sure (if it grows fully). This is a rental house and so I don't want that happening.

Questions:

1. Is this plant correctly identified by me?
2. How do I uproot it safely?
3. Where should I transplant it?
4. Any other care instructions? Eventually if it grows big and I don't own a house I'll give it away to a friend/neighbor who has yard space.

[image: cali walnut and my hand for size ref]

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy to transplant a small tree like that.

Cut a circle around it with a spade, about a foot away from the stem and as deep as the spade will go in. Then try to get the spade underneath it and lift out the complete cylinder of earth and the tree all in one piece.

Make the planting hole as close to the same size as possible. If you succeed in not disturbing the soil around the roots, the tree will hardly notice it has been transplanted.

Comment: I think the space around it, the depth and width that the roots expanded to under the concrete, etc made it hard for me. Eventually it died :(
Hopefully the next time I run into this situation I do better!